# javascript - detect print (not print preview) event

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have a custom print preview page that shows up when a user wants to print a page. After this page, the user is directed to the browser print preview page (where you select printer, print options, etc.). If the user actually prints the page, then I want to hide my custom print preview page. If the user cancels the print, then I want to keep the custom print preview page visible.

**I need to be able to determine if a user has printed a page.**

I read that IE has `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint` methods, but wanted to know if there is something that will work for other browsers too.

Answer (score 0):

The watchMedia API could be used for it I think, but I never tried. See more infos [here](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/) (they have a example about printing) and good luck !