# Track Print event in GA Through GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am new to GTM ,I have learned to track events like click and link click for different classes,but now i want track the print event from user,so can anyone please help me what steps should be done ,if a user tries to print the page .Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no cross-browser javascript print event (ie has onbeforeprint), which makes sense since the print menu item is part  of the chrome (damn you Google for confusing people about the difference between the browser chrome and the chrome browser - the former used to denote the "borders of a Web browser window, which include the window frames, menus, toolbars and scroll bars") and should not be accessible via javascript (a print button in the page could be detected with a click event).

[Here is an article](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/) where somebody tried to create a cross-browser solution by combining onbeforeprint (for ie) with  window.matchMedia (on the assumption that on print the print style sheets  will be matched). This did not result in a particularly reliable solution.

There is [already an (old and un-accepted) answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990233/javascript-detect-print-not-print-preview-event) that references this article and since there has been no progress since 2012 I think we can safely declare that there is no reliable cross-browser solution to detect print, hence you cannot trigger an GTM tag based on print, hence you cannot track print.